# How to get the download warning back?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

When trying to download files from the internet a brand new tor browser would throw a warning like

> you're about to download something, it can't potentially be dangerous, blah blah blah, click ok to continue

I seemed to have disabled that warning at some point. Not sure how to get it back. Is there a variable in `about:config` I can use to switch it back on?

Answer (score 1):

The preference you're looking for is:

`extensions.torbutton.launch_warning` which should be set to `true`.

This option is important for Tor Browser's anti-forensic properties, as it stops Firefox from starting to opportunistically download offered files to disk in the background before a user has decided where or if to save the file.

This could be used to maliciously "taint" a disk with a unique identifier (for later forensic analysts to find), or accidentally leave traces of activity on disk when you're using it.

Tails disables this, since it doesn't write to disk, only to RAM.